# watchEffect with side effect but without infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, watch, vue-composition-api

what I am trying to do is:

1. construct an URL based on props
2. initially and whenever the URL changes, fetch some data

Since this is asynchronous and I also want to indicate loading, I use this construct:

```js
const pageUrl = computed(() => `/api/${props.foo}/${props.bar}`)

const state = reactive({
    page: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
})

watchEffect(async () => {
    state.loading = true
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(pageUrl.value)
      state.page = resp.data
    } catch (err) {
      state.error = err
      console.log(err)
    }

    state.loading = false
})

// return page, loading, error for the component to use
```

The problem is that this seems to run in an infinite loop because in the body, I am not only reacting to the `pageUrl`, but also to `state` which itself is modified in the function body.

Alternatively, I can use `watch(pageUrl, async pageUrl => { ... })`, but this seems only to be triggered when `pageUrl` changes (in my case: I modify the URL because the props are updated via `vue-router`, but not when I *initially* visit the URL).

What should I do here, is my idea of signalling the loading state not appropriate here?

From a logical point of view, the `page` is a computed value, the only reason I use `watch` here is that it's asynchronous and might yield an error as well.

Comment: If you're using Vue 2 with the composition API plugin there seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/498) that's related to this.

Comment: Thank you so much - the example in the bug is pretty much mine. And yes, it's vue 2 since I need vuetify which is not ready for vue 3 I think.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Husam I got aware of the bug, and it seems like changing a piece of state *twice* introduces this behaviour - in my case setting `loading` to `true` and then again to `false`.

This behaviour is not apparent in Vue3, and a workaround (and in general maybe the much cleaner method) could be to directly use `watch` instead of `watchEffect`.

[The source code](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/master/src/apis/watch.ts) shows different overloads of the funciton, and there is an `options` argument that is not directly documented in the Vue3 API. There, I found that my call above needs to read like `watch(value, async value => { effect }, { immediate: true })`.